# Google Apps Script - only write new rows from spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, sql, google-apps-script

I'm writing a script for an insurance agency that will work like this:

1. When an employee makes a sale, they enter information about each policy they sold (name, policy number, etc.) in their own Google Spreadsheet, one policy per row.
2. Script takes spreadsheets from every employee as input and writes them to a table in database.
3. When policies get paid, they get written to a separate table.
4. I use an OUTER JOIN to see which employee sold each paid policy.

The issue I'm having is that in step 2, I don't want to write policies to the database that have already been written (i.e. because they were there last time I ran the script). I can think of a few ways to solve this...

1. Clear the table every time I run the script, so it's being written fresh every time.
2. Loop through and check if a given policy is already in the database before writing it to DB.
3. Add a boolean column called "copied to DB", when adding rows to DB check if "copied to DB" is equal to "Yes": if true, don't write the row to DB; if false, change "copied to DB" to yes and write the row to the DB.

I think any of the above methods would work, but they all seem pretty inefficient. Is there anything in SQL or Google Apps Script that would do this more efficiently and minimize database writes?

Currently, the way I'm doing step 2 is I'm copying all the employee sheets to a single "master sheet" that contains all the employees policies, and every time I run the script I clear the master spreadsheet and then copy all the data in, so there are no duplicate rows. This is basically equivalent to method #1 above, but again, it seems like there should be a better way to do this than clearing the spreadsheet every time. (And I'd rather use a database table than writing all the data to a spreadsheet.)

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like "INSERT IGNORE" might work for this. Looking into it now.

Comment: I like the idea of a cell in the SS showing that it's been written to the datastore, but perhaps instead of a simple Boolean, you could input the id of the datastore object. This might serve a higher purpose in the future, and you won't have to loop through your database to see if the row has already been written.

Comment: Why wouldn't I have to loop through if I did it that way?

Comment: Well if your cell 'dbId' or whatever has a value, you will know that it's been written without ever touching your db. A query won't be necessary, just a write.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if the spreadsheet rows are 1) always appended, 2) never changed or deleted.
Loop for each spreadsheet:
Remember in a script property the last row written to the db (one property per spreadsheet, base the script property name on the spreadsheet id).
Start from the row after that last one, write to db and afterwards write the property.
Make your db row primary key something like 'spreadsheet id + row number', and use 'insert or ignore' or equivalent. This is a must for integrity as a script could fail after a db write but before writing the script property for that spreadsheet.

I have a popular chrome extension that does this well for thousands of users.

Comment: Thanks Zig. Do you have a link to the extension?

Comment: Yes (doesnt use apps script) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plus-for-trello/gjjpophepkbhejnglcmkdnncmaanojkf?hl=en